# Insert function at controller with model doesn't work in codeigniter4.. How can I solve this?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I've been facing the problem since two days ago. But, can't fix it either. I have submitted all the necessary coding information below. Please, help me out.
Here is my controller...

```
    <?php namespace App\Controllers;

    use App\Models\UserModel;
    use App\Controllers\BaseController;


    class UserController extends BaseController
   {
     protected $userModel;
     public function __construct()
     {
        $this->userModel = new UserModel();
     }

    public function registration() {
        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'):
            $rules = $this->userModel->getValidationRules(['only' => ['user', 'email', 'password', 
            'confirm_password', 'gender']]);
            if(!$this->validate($rules)):
                $this->session->setFlashdata('errors', $this->validator->getErrors());
                return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        else:
                $data = $this->request->getPost();
                unset($data['confirm_password'], $data['registration'], $data['ci4app_auto_fill']);
                if($this->userModel->insert($data)):
                    $this->session->setFlashdata('success', 'Your registration has been done successfully. Thank you.');
                    return redirect()->to('login');
                else:
                    echo "Sorry! Your registration has not been successful. Please, try again. Thank you.";
                endif;
            endif;
        endif;
    }

    }
```

and here is my model

```
    <?php namespace App\Models;

    use CodeIgniter\Model;

    class UserModel extends Model
    {
    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $allowedFields = ['user', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'gender', 'password', 'address', 
    'city', 'estate', 'country', 'image'];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['hashPassword'];
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;
    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';
    protected $validationRules = [
        'user'              => [
                'label'         => 'User ID',
                'rules'         => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.user,id,{id}]|alpha_numeric|min_length[3]'
        ],
        'gender'            => [
            'label'             => 'Gender',
            'rules'             => 'trim|required'
        ],
        'email'             => [
            'label'             => 'E-mail ID',
            'rules'             => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email,id,{id}]|valid_email'
        ],
        'password'          => [
            'label'             => 'Password',
            'rules'             => 'trim|required|min_length[5]'
        ],
        'confirm_password'  => [
            'label'             => "Password Confirmation",
            'rules'             => 'trim|required|matches[password]'
        ],
        'phone'             => [
            'label'             => 'Phone Number',
            'rules'             => 'trim|numeric|max_length[13]|is_unique[users.phone,id,{id}]'
        ],
        'address'           => [
            'label'             => 'Address',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_numeric_space'
        ],
        'city'              => [
            'label'             => 'City',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_numeric_space'
        ],
        'estate'            => [
            'label'             => 'Estate',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_space'
        ],
        'country'           => [
            'label'             => 'Country',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_space'
        ]
    ];
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation     = false;

    public function hashPassword($data) {
        if(! isset($data['data']['password'])) return $data;
        $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Neither data is being inserted nor any error has occurred!
What is the problem for I couldn't insert data into my database?
Now please tell me, how I can solve this problem. Thank you...

Comment: Did you try to debug yourself? If yes, what did you do exactly? Try breaking this large problem in a small example, with less variable etc... One operation at the time.

Comment: Thanks, @Gildas, for your cordial response. Yes, I did. before trying to insert in database with $this->userModel->insert($data), everything is ok. But, As soon as I try to insert data, and see the result with var_dump, found bool false, means no data has been inserted, and so happens. But no error message has been generated. That's the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: You are validating your date two times, not sure if thats the problem but that is happening here. If you declare your validation rules in the model they will run automatically in all insert and update actions, no need to load those validation rules in the controller and running them there.

Comment: Thank you very much @marcogmonteiro . Then, I had to define a class-  public function insertData($data) { if($this->db->table('users')->insert($data)): return true; endif; } - in model and call it like $this->userModel->insertData($data) in controller. Then, It worked and data be inserted. But, the problem is, that time my hashPassword() function didn't work whic is bound to $beforeInsert event as showed at avob post in the code section, and so password didn't get hashed. In contrast, If I want to use insert furntion in controller, then how can I get selected some validation rules from all.

Comment: use the default insert method and print the $this->userModel->errors() when it fails. Maybe there's some validation rule that is not passing because you might be sending the wrong data.

Comment: Yes, @marcogmonteiro. I had tried it before. But, that didn't work. That's why I had to go through the another option. Now, Only god can save me. ha ha... Anyway, Thank you again for your cordial cooperation.